# The injection point has the following annotations: @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

Hello there I am new to spring boot, i am getting this error since a while, unfortunately can't fix it. I am googling since then but still not find what i did wrong. I believe the error exists in the Service Class. I tried to remove the field injection ( @Autowired) and implemented as a constructor injection but that did not work as well Find below my code:

Entity:

```
package com.devops.maven.cars_api_maven.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import javax.persistence.*;

@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@Entity
@Table(name = "CARS")
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq", initialValue=4, allocationSize=100)
public class Car {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="seq")
    private Long id;
    String manufacturer;
    String model;
    int build;

    public Car() {
    }

    public Car(Long id, String manufacturer, String model, int build) {
        this.id = id;
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.model = model;
        this.build = build;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public int getBuild() {
        return build;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public void setBuild(int build) {
        this.build = build;
    }
}
```

DAO

```
package com.devops.maven.cars_api_maven.repositories;

import com.devops.maven.cars_api_maven.model.Car;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public interface CarsRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Long> {
}
```

Main

```
package com.devops.maven.cars_api_maven;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;



@SpringBootApplication (
        exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class },
        scanBasePackages={
            "com.devops.maven", "com.devop.application"}
        )

    public class CarsApplication {
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(CarsApplication.class, args);
        }
}
```

Service Class

```
package com.devops.maven.cars_api_maven;

import com.devops.maven.cars_api_maven.model.Car;
import com.devops.maven.cars_api_maven.repositories.CarsRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("cars")
@Service
public class CarsController {
   @Autowired
   private CarsRepository repository;

    @GetMapping
    public List<Car> getCars() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Car addCar(@RequestBody Car car) {
        return repository.save(car);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public Car getCarById(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        return repository.getOne(id);
    }

    @DeleteMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public void removeCarById(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        repository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

Error output:

> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Field repository in com.devops.maven.cars_api_maven.CarsController
> required a bean of type
> 'com.devops.maven.cars_api_maven.repositories.CarsRepository' that
> could not be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>
> - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
> 'com.devops.maven.cars_api_maven.repositories.CarsRepository' in your
> configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove `exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class }` from below class and run again. It will fix the issue.

```java
package com.devops.maven.cars_api_maven;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;


@SpringBootApplication (
        exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class },
        scanBasePackages={
            "com.devops.maven", "com.devop.application"}
        )

    public class CarsApplication {
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(CarsApplication.class, args);
        }
}
```

Comment: When i remove it i get the following error   Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
 If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
 If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

Comment: Yes, either you need to use H2 database or some other database. If you are creating Repository and Entity classes then a database is required. If you will use H2 database then no need to add any JPA property in application.properties

Comment: Can you please assist me on how to do that?

Comment: Please add the below dependency in pom.xml                            
            <dependency>
   <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
   <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>

Comment: Good to hear that it solved your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue once. I didn't follow package conventions so spring boot couldn't find those classes/bean correctly. Even "scanBasePackages" didn't work.

Wrong package declarations:

```
 Ex. com.example.course.dao
     services
     com.example.controller
     course.entities
```

Correct declaration:

```
Ex. com.example.course.dao
     com.example.course.services
     com.example.course.controller
     com.example.course.entities
```

I hope this may help someone.